# Custom WPF DataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, user-controls

im trying for the past week or so to make custom columns for the wpf datagrid

the main point is that there are certain types of data that i display in multiple datagrids across the app, and i dont want to redeclare all the attributes everytime

heres a sample of some code thats used again and again

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PersonID}" SelectedValuePath="PersonID" DisplayMemberPath="PersonName" Header="Customer" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonSource}}" />
```

so i tried making a usercontrol like this

```
Public Class PersonColumn
Inherits DataGridComboBoxColumn
Sub New()
    SelectedValuePath = "PersonID"
    DisplayMemberPath = "PersonName"
    Header = "Customer"
End Sub
End Class
```

this is a help, but not complete , because

1. i cant do any styling or other markup work
2. i cant seem to use the `FindResource` command to get the PersonSource

how can this be improved? all my searches show xaml redone again and again, this seems very redundant

at the same time im trying to make a datepicker column but cant find any sample of a **reusable** column, just redefining in each datagrid again

thank you very much

**EDIT**

im now trying a totally different direction

i made a usercontrol with the following markup

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"      xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SampleWpf"  x:Class="DateColumn">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:DateColumn}}, Path=Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:DateColumn}}, Path=Value}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

and a bit of codebehind

```
Public Class DateColumn
Inherits DataGridTemplateColumn
Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(Date?), GetType(DateColumn))
Property Value As Date?
End Class
```

but this is not working. the date is not showing up in the column, neither are my changes saved back to the datasource

the datagrid xaml is dead simple

```
                <my:DateColumn   Value="{Binding Path=ReceivedOn}" Header="ReceivedOn" />
```

how are you all doing these stuff?
thanks a billion!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a reusable `DataTemplate` in your Application's Resources, then just add a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with the specified `CellTemplate`

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{DynamicResource CustomColumnTemplate}" />
```

Comment: thanks. but if i want to add custom attributes to my column, how can i do that? i.e. i want to add a MinAge property that i can set MinAge="10" then the column will only display persons over age 10. i would probably need some coding also. i can't do all that in a resource, can i? thanks!

Comment: @Yisman It would be a better idea to apply a filter to your DataGrid's ItemSource

Comment: i mean to filter the combobox results

Comment: hi. does anybody have any ideas for me? i'm sure you're all using some sort of solution for these situations ;-)